# Converting list of clauses to a query?

Tags: list, prolog, call, clause

let say i have the following facts :

```
book(65).
own(named('Peter'), 65).
```

now got the query as a list of clauses :

```
 [what(A), own(named('Peter'), A)]
```

or

```
 [who(X), book(A), own(X, A)] .
```

how do I make a rule that accept this list and return the result. Keep in mind that the question could be Why,When,Who...

I went the usual way :

```
query_lst([]).
%% query_lst([what(Q)|T], Q) :- query_lst(T). 
query_lst([H|T]) :- write('?- '),writeln(H), 
    call(H), query_lst(T).
```

but this does not allow binding of Q in wh(Q) to the answer which could be in any of the facts that are called by call()

---

Additional complication I did not forsee is that the query :

```
(what(A), own(named('Peter'), A).
```

would fail, because there is no what(X), fact in the DB.
I have to just bind somehow the variable A /that is in what()/ to query_lst(Goals,A) and of course remove what(X) from the list /which i can do with select/3 /

any idea how to bind list-Wh-var to query_lst result ?

---

my current solution (assumes Q is first element):

```
 query_lst([G|Gs],Res) :- G =.. [Q,Res], member(Q,[what,why,who,when]), lst2conj(Gs,Conj), call(Conj).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert the list of goals into a conjunction and call it:

```
list_to_conjunction([], true).
list_to_conjunction([Goal| Goals], Conjunction) :-
    list_to_conjunction(Goals, Goal, Conjunction).

list_to_conjunction([], Conjunction, Conjunction).
list_to_conjunction([Next| Goals], Goal, (Goal,Conjunction)) :-
    list_to_conjunction(Goals, Next, Conjunction).
```

Then:

```
query_list(Goals) :-
    list_to_conjunction(Goals, Conjunction),
    call(Conjunction).
```

Comment: thanks ... just curious why cant we cant achieve the same thing with just one of l2c()...this seems like it should work : l2c([G|Gs],Conj) :- l2c(Gs,(Conj,G)).
 but the l2c([],_). make it impossible ..

Comment: The definition of the `list_to_conjunction /2` predicate takes advantage of first-argument indexing to avoid spurious choice-points when called with a list of bound terms. It also avoids adding a redundant call to `true/0` at the end of the conjunction (with a non-empty list of goals).

Comment: first-argument indexing  ?

Answer (score 1):

You got an answer, but it was an answer to your *question*, not to *what you really wanted*. Also, you edited your question after you accepted that answer, which isn't very helpful. Typically it's better to open a new question when you have... a new question.

Here is an answer to *what you seem to want*, which is not exactly what you asked. You have lists of the form `[WhPart | Rest]` where the `WhPart` is a wh-word with a variable, and the `Rest` is a list of goals. You want to execute these goals and get the variable in the wh-term bound.

The good news is that, since the variable in the wh-word also occurs in the goals, it will be bound if you execute them. No extra work is needed. Executing the goals is enough. If the wh-part is really at the start of the list, you can do the whole thing like this:

```
query([_WhPart | Body]) :-
    call_body(Body).

call_body([]).
call_body([Goal | Goals]) :-
    call(Goal),
    call_body(Goals).
```

For example:

```
?- query([who(X), book(A), own(X, A)]).
X = named('Peter'),
A = 65.

?- query([what(A), own(named('Peter'), A)]).
A = 65.
```

As you can see, there is no need to convert the query to a conjunctive goal: Executing the queries in sequence is exactly the same as executing their conjunction.

Also, it doesn't actually matter which wh-word is used; the only thing that really matters is the variable contained within the term. For this reason the above version does no checking at all, and the `_WhPart` could be anything. If you want to check that it is a valid term, you can do the following:

```
query([WhPart | Body]) :-
    wh(WhPart),
    call_body(Body).

wh(who(_X)).
wh(what(_X)).
wh(when(_X)).
```

This buys you some "type checking":

```
?- query([foo(A), own(named('Peter'), A)]).
false.
```

But not a lot, since you don't know if the wh-word actually fits what is being asked:

```
?- query([when(A), own(named('Peter'), A)]).
A = 65.
```

Comment: nice.. but the list is hidden..f.e.. generate(Txt,GLst),query(GLst) ... you simply get back true|false, but not the unified Wh-variable, because it does not 'surface' trough the whole process !!

Comment: You could define `wh(who(X), X). wh(what(X), X).` etc., then `query(X, [WhPart | Body]) :- wh(WhPart, X), call_body(Body).` to surface the variable.